# How can i generate an image determining the color of each pixel in python?

Tags: python, image

I need a way to generate an image so that i can decide width, length and color for each pixel, maybe through an array. how can i do that in Python?

Comment: Did you try anything ? It is not a good idea to just ask for help without showing your efforts

Comment: i searched for that on google but didn't find anything

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a way using Pillow and an array**

```
from PIL import Image

# Your image as a 3d-array using RGB color values for each pixel
imageArray = [[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
              [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
              [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]]

# Generate image
img = Image.new("RGB", (len(imageArray[0]), len(imageArray)), "#ffffff")

for i, row in enumerate(imageArray):
    for j, pixel in enumerate(row):
        img.putpixel((j, i), pixel)

img.save("output.png")
```

Comment: I think your answer would be better if 1) your image wasn't exactly square at 3x3 because that would help show whether height or width is specified first 2) your image wasn't just black, how about a red `+` sign on a blue background or something visual? Also, you really should try to avoid nested `for` loops with Python images - they are hopelessly slow. Try to use Numpy, or Pillow's vectorised C code.